# g++ gives error : invalid initialization of reference of type ‘char&’ from expression of type ‘unsigned char’

Tags: c++, reference, initialization

when I try to compile the following code

```
int main()
{
    unsigned char uc;
    char & rc = uc;
}
```

g++ gives the following error : invalid initialization of reference of type ‘char&’ from expression of type ‘unsigned char’. The same happens when using signed char instead of unsigned char.
But the following compiles well

```
int main()
{
    unsigned char uc;
    const char & rc = uc;
}
```

Why isn't it possible to initialize 'char &' with a variable of type 'unsigned char' while it is possible to initialize 'const char &' with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Why isn't it possible to initialize 'char &' with a variable of type 'unsigned char' while it is possible to initialize 'const char &' with it?*

Because the latter creates a temporary to bind to the const reference when the `unsigned char` is converted to a `char`, something you can't do with non-const references. `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` are three distinct types, as explained in C++11 § 3.9.1:

> Plain char, signed char, and unsigned char are three distinct types

Comment: What is the difference between `char` and `signed char`?

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie: On some compilers, `char` might be unsigned.  But ignoring that, the three types are always three different types, even though two of them behave the same.  This makes a difference for pointers, references, function overloads, and template arguments.

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie, `char` can be either signed or unsigned - it's up to the implementation - but as clearly stated, all three are distinct types, so it's not like an implementation can do `typedef signed char char;`.

Answer (score 0):

"The C++ compiler treats variables of type char, signed char, and unsigned char as having different types."

The following link will clarify: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc953fe1.aspx

change the following:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned char uc;
    unsigned char& rc = uc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced to this error today, and just would like to share what I have found.

Bjarne Stroustrup in his book "The C++ Programming Language" Third Edition wrote:

> § 5.5 References
>
> Initialization of a reference is trivial when the initializer is an
>   lvalue (an object whose address you can take; see §4.9.6). The
>   initializer for a ‘‘plain’’ **T&** must be an lvalue of type **T**.
>
> The initializer for a const T& need not be an lvalue or even of type T
>   In such cases,
>
> [1] first, implicit type conversion to T is applied if necessary (see
>   §C.6)
>
> [2] then, the resulting value is placed in a temporary variable of
>   type T and
>
> [3] finally, this temporary variable is used as the value of the
>   initializer.